# Google App Engine - Datastore Viewer - GQL Query

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

We have a data store and I want to get some insight on some things like a size sold on a specific date and between dates with GQL.

So basically I want to see 'item', a specific KEY id for size and for a specific time / time range

So first off I made a query for just the first part (Items with Key ID):

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE size = KEY('Size', xxxx)
```

which works. Then a date range

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE sold_date > DATETIME(2013-11-05 16:57:45) AND  sold_date < DATETIME('2013-11-10 16:57:45')
```

which also works

Combining these two however seems impossible. For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE size = KEY('Size', xxxx) AND sold_date > DATETIME('2013-11-05 16:57:45')
```

how can I combine these?

And then also when I want to see a set of sizes the query does not work. For instance

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE size = (KEY('Size', xxxx), KEY('Size',xxxx))
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: "seems impossible"... what happens when you run it? You get no data? you get an error message? this is pretty much necessary to help understand what you do here. In the meantime, the answer posted here does look like the correct answer (also, in the future, please keep Stack questions to one question per post. If you want to select from a set of sizes, that's one question. The query not working is another :). This helps people find your questions in the future, which is the whole point of the site (not just give you an answer, but have an answer for the next coder with the same issue :) )

Answer (score 1):

To query on multiple properties you will need to create a custom index (I'd recommend reading the docs first: [java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes) / [python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes)). For example (Java):

```
<datastore-index kind="Item">
    <property name="size" direction="asc" />
    <property name="sold_date" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
```

Or yaml:

```
indexes:
- kind: Item
  properties:
  - name: size
  - name: sold_date
```

If you want to select entities with properties matching a set you need to use `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE size IN ( key('Size', 'xxx'), key('Size','yyy') )
```

[GQL reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference?hl=en)